# How to model sub components of a dependent variable?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, multicollinearity, logit, endogeneity

I am have a modeling issue that I am hoping to have answered. I am analyzing high school math state proficiency data (a binary variable Y; 1 if the student is proficient in math for that year and 0 otherwise). The math test is comprised of five sub-components/parts (each can be defined as X1 to X5). Students' overall proficiency level (Y) depends on their scores on each individual sub-component.

If I want to do an analysis showing, for example, which sub-component score (X1 - X5) can best predict student proficiency (Y), how would I model this? Clearly, X1 through X5 are endogenous. When I use a logit model, my odds ratios are enormously high. However, the predictive probabilities and other margins commands (in Stata) seem reasonable.

I am confused if I can still use the logit model for my purposes? Or if someone could point me the direction of another modeling technique I should be using? Also, do these type of models have a name?

Comment: When using exclusively continuous variables as predictors, (logistic) regression is sometimes performed on standardized data so the effect estimates/odds ratios all represent the change in outcome/odds of outcome for a standard deviation increase of the predictor. This way you could compare sub-components based on their effect size, while taking into account some sub-components might be on another (continuous) scale. Another way could be to look at measures of discrimination to see how well models based on one of the sub-components set apart the two outcome categories (sufficient or not).